# Ubuntu 15.04 not reading or creating .eps file correctly.

Tags: 15.04, eps

After upgrading from 14.04 to 15.04 when I am generating **.eps** file for a software package **xmgrace** its not showing output file irrespective of background. If the same file I open in **GIMP** or by virtual machine in **Illustrator** its working there. Please help me, try to fix this problem.

Comment: Without a sample file that is difficult to say. Run this command `apt-cache policy grace` and post the output in your question.

Comment: grace:
  Installed: 1:5.1.25-1
  Candidate: 1:5.1.25-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:5.1.25-1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: It not about grace, I have many older .eps files which is not opening in Ubuntu 15.04 . If you need I can send you those file .

Comment: Ok, give me a link :)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2sAMq2UpxmYfl9KX1ljc1lGa3lkdFYtUEJUY0hkYk5xa3pEaE9QLWpDY0FrY21yUXRjOTA&usp=sharing

Comment: Its is google drive, Please Check in Ubuntu 15.04 not in any other version. 14.10 it is fine.

Comment: I have been using both LibreOffice and FIJI to create eps files and they always come out blank. I have just recently upgraded to 15.04. My workaround is to output to pdf and convert to eps using epspdf

Comment: But I actually need them. In 14.04/14.10 it was black and you open you find some lines but in 15.04 no black space as well